# .htaccess and .htpasswd to prevent access to folder problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a website admin area I want to protect with a password..

so inside the admin folder I put an .htaccess and .htpasswd files containing this:

**.htaccess:**

```
AuthUserFile C:/wamp/www/website_project/admin/.htpasswd
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd:** (generated using an online tool)

```
admin:sOSDxAdJI4xx2
```

When I go to the admin folder, a popup is shown where I need to insert username and password... so until now its working fine, BUT no matter if I insert a correct password or not I get the same popup again when I hit 'enter', I can never access the folder...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Exclude first the possibility that the online tool is wrong. Try `admin:$1$BZMs42TN$oUraNSkgHERtU0bPZxGqE0` it should equal `admin:arrrgh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `AuthUserFile` line, it looks like you're using Apache on Windows, which has a different default password encryption algorithm than other platforms. Try using the `htpasswd` command-line tool to generate the password and see if you still have the same problem.